# Is there any comprehensive tutorial on how to use this kind of structural typing?

Tags: scala, types, scalaz

As seen [here](http://typeclassopedia.bitbucket.org/#slide-31), map is defined

> in a slightly funky way

For completeness' sake, here's the code:

```
implicit def FunctionFunctor[R] = new Functor[({type l[a] = R=>a})#l] {
  def map[A, B](fa: R => A)(f: A => B) : R => B = (x => f(fa(x)))
}
```

More concretely - `new Functor[({type l[a] = R=>a})#l]`

I do think I know what's going on, but can't say honestly that I fully understand the concept. And since there is no any hint, I can't event google the term (I simply don't know that to google). Does some tutorial (or review, or whatever) exist where this is explained with a better level of detalization? I'd appreciate even more is someone could explain it right here in the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a special case of structural typing but called a 'type lambda', if you search for `type lambda scala` google will give you some results.

In short, it's used in a similar fashion as partially applied functions.

```
def x(a:Int, b:Int):Int = a * b
val x10 = x(10, _:Int)
x10(2) // 2
```

An example with types.

```
type IntEither[B] = Either[Int, B]
val y:IntEither[String] // Either[Int, String]
```

In some cases methods or classes expect a type with a single parameter

```
class Test[F[_]]
```

You can not give the `Test` class an `Either` because `Test` expects a type with 1 parameter and `Either` has 2. In order to be able to pass in an `Either` we can partially apply it

```
type X[B] = Either[Int, B]
new Test[X]
```

An alternative way of writing it is like this:

```
type X = {
  type T[x] = Either[Int, x]
}

new Test[X#T]
```

Instead of creating a type alias, we can also define the `X` type anonymously

```
new Test[({type T[x] = Either[Int, x]})#T]
```

These all give you an instance of type `Test[Either[Int, x]]`.

---

**Edit**

Your example could look like this:

```
type PartiallyTypedFunction[R] = {
  type T[x] = R => x 
}

implicit def FunctionFunctor[R] =
  new Functor[PartiallyTypedFunction[R]#T] {
    def map[A, B](fa: R => A)(f: A => B): R => B = (x => f(fa(x)))
  }
```

Comment: Indeed, it looks way too complicated. That's why I usually create a type alias or even a trait or a class to prevent using that horrible syntax.

Comment: @cdshines I've added an example of the code you posted using a type alias.

Comment: Thank you. As about now this looks like the most comprehensive post on all the internetz concerning the subject:)